# Question on re-creating a sound I heard in a pop song on the radio

Tags: sound-design, ableton-live

This is my first time on this site, and I hope I'm posting to the right place.

I'm looking for some help on how I can re-create or find a similar sound from the song "Don't Let Me Down" by the Chain Smokers. I'm attempting to see if I can re-create the beat and do a parody of it. It's the lead sound right at the drop, around 1:05 in the video below. It sounds like there is a gliding aspect to it, or possibly a pitch bend, but I can't be too sure. Please help, thanks!

I'm using Ableton Live, I have Native Complete, Massive, and omnisphere.

Answer (score 1):

I tried to reproduce it on Massive.

If you want reproduce a similar sound on Massive, follow this steps:

1. Choose a wav from one osc
2. Change the pitch from 0 -> 64.00
3. Use an envelope to move this pitch from -64.00

**Note: the envelope must be with slow attack, otherwise you make a percussive sound**

Suggestion: (i did it)

If you want a bigger sound, more than this:
add another osc (use the same env for all osc)
if you want, apply a filter and apply a env to shift filter frequency.